# Add multiple markers on the map and search the marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing one app where i am adding multiple markers of hotels and restaurants through array list.It is working fine.but now I want to search the marker by typing in edit text. If the marker is present use   `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo()` to zoom that particular location.
Please Help me.I am trying but no solution is working for me.Please help me.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: Please post a code example of your attempt.

Comment: Since your markers are in an array list, can't you just search through the list?

Comment: I want to design application like store locator in android.I have search it out,but it is in java script and html. I want to implement it using Android Studio .https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator.

Answer (score 0):

Create an list with custom objects containing marker objects or their ids. Every time you add or remove marker - also update a list.
And while searching just search your list for markers meeting criteria.

Comment: I want to design application like store locator in android.I have search it out,but it is in java script and html. I want to implement it using Android Studio .https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator.